# DataVisualization is not declared

Tags: vb.net, data-visualization

I started a new VB project, and added existing items (code modules) from another project to get started.
Now I'm getting all kinds of error messages related to "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" members not being defined.
Even with the entire, fully qualified, names I'm still getting errors about not being defined.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` in the new project?

Comment: That namespace is for the `Chart` control and associated types. The reference that Plutonix mentioned would normally be added automatically when you add a `Chart` control to a form but, if you haven't done that in this case, you need to add the reference manually. Either that or add a `Chart` control to a form and then delete it, which would leave behind the reference.

Comment: I added the reference and it worked. Thanks for the help!